# Spliting Dictionary String Values - Python

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, split

I have four types: AAA, BBB, CCC, and FUN. I am writing a function that will receive a dictionary of these types in pairs of two as strings. (The dictionary will contain only 3 random pairings i.e:

```
Example01 = { "AAA-BBB": 123, "AAA-CCC": 456, "BBB-CCC": 789}
Example02 = {"FUN-AAA": 111,"FUN-BBB": 222,"FUN-CCC": 333}
```

I need to run calculations on the various parings, but I am having trouble reading in the string keys...

First Issue:

One issue is that I can receive `"FUN-AAA"` or `"AAA-FUN"` and they are the same thing (i.e. `"FUN-AAA"` = `"AAA-FUN"`). How can I manipulate the dictionary keys so that I can read those two keys as being equal?

Second issue:

When I receive `{"FUN-AAA": 1 , "FUN-CCC": 2, "FUN-BBB": 3}` if I read the key in as a whole string that would suggest three distinct values, but in reality I need to know that `'FUN'` has shown up on 3 of the 3 records... I was thinking of splitting the string in the dictionary, but could not find a proper way to do so.  In other words I basically need to know how to count how many times `"FUN"` showed up and its respective value, so the above example would be...

> FUN ==> 3 ==> 6 (the sum)
>
> AAA ==> 1 ==> 1 (the sum)
>
> BBB ==> 1 ==> 3 (the sum)
>
> CCC ==> 1 ==> 2 (the sum)

Comment: Given your second requirement, your first requirement seems meaningless.

Comment: I can see why you would say that kindall, but its relevant for other parts of the calculation I didn't include in the question above... One example, which I thought just made the question wordy, is if I need to check for incorrect data i.e. receiving "FUN-AAA", "AAA-FUN", and "CCC-BBB" this shouldn't happen cause i shouldn't get the pair repeated like that... So I wanted a test that I can put at the beginning of the function to reject the data if it is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> counts = defaultdict(list)
>>> example02 = {"FUN-AAA": 111,"FUN-BBB": 222,"FUN-CCC": 333}
>>> for key,value in example02.items():
...      for k in key.split("-"):
...          counts[k].append(value)
...
>>> counts
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'FUN': [111, 222, 333], 'AAA': [111], 'BBB': [222], 
'CCC': [333]})
```

Getting the counts is easy:

```
>>> [(key,len(items)) for key,items in counts.items()]
[('FUN', 3), ('AAA', 1), ('BBB', 1), ('CCC', 1)]
```

and the sums as well:

```
>>> [(key,sum(items)) for key,items in counts.items()]
[('FUN', 666), ('AAA', 111), ('BBB', 222), ('CCC', 333)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your requirements you can just process each key in a pair separately:

```
pairs = {"FUN-AAA": 1 , "FUN-CCC": 2, "FUN-BBB": 3}
counts = {}
sums = {}
for pair, value in pairs.items():
    keys = pair.split('-')
    for key in keys:
        counts[key] = 1 + counts.get(key, 0)
        sums[key] = value + sums.get(key, 0)
print counts
print sums
```